# Script to ban IPs that try to enter root on server

Tags: centos, iptables

Is there such a script that blocks IPs that try more than 3-4 times to access root? Because everytime I open the server (CentOS) i get the message that root has been brute forced (bots obviously). I have their IPs but I don't want to manually ban them with `iptables -A INPUT -s IP-ADDRESS -j DROP`.

Comment: best option : **Disable** root login. Other : `fail2ban` or `DenyHosts` is your friend

Comment: And if you want to go on with banning, something like [fail2ban](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171735/44760) should do the trick.

Comment: Used fail2ban and it worked.

Comment: or instead of disabling root login entirely, restrict it to authorized_keys only with `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  Alternatively, use `forced-commands-only` and have different keys in `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` to run different things as root.   remote root access without going via a user and sudo can be useful.

Comment: IMO the only time you should use a password for an ssh login is when you're first adding your public key(s) to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard tool for the job is `fail2ban`. It bans for a certain time an IP address that tried to login unsuccessfully, and it is highly configurable.

It is not available on the standard CentOS repositories, you have to install the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repo first.

On CentOS 6:

```
yum install http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

On CentOS 7:

```
yum install http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-1.noarch.rpm
```

and then:

```
yum install fail2ban
```

Note: it is highly recommended that you disable root login (this is done in the configuration of `sshd`).

Comment: Worked like a charm with it. Also works if you install it by Plesk web host edition.